# Why the switch statement automatically answers to "default"

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

i'm trying to learn JavaScript at home, and i'm doing some basic programs, on this one, i'm trying to use the switch statement but i don't understand why it automatically answers "default"

```js
let note = Number(prompt("Quel note as tu eu au baccalauréat?"));

switch (note) {
  case (note < 10):
   console.log("Tu es refusé, retente ta chance l'année prochaine");
    break;
  case ((note => 10) && (note <= 12)):
   console.log("Tu as réussi l'éxamen, félicitations");
    break;
  case (note > 12):
   console.log("Félicitations, tu as réussi ton examen avec mention");
    break;
  default: console.log("Entre une note comprise entre 0 et 20")
  }
```

Comment: That's not how `switch` should be used. If you're using comparisons like that for each case you should use an if/else statement instead. `switch` evaluates an expression then matches that result to a specific case.

Comment: Huh, okay thanks for the answers, i'm about to try with the if/else statement

Comment: `note => 10` is a function, not a comparison. Did you mean `note >= 10`?

Answer (score 1):

Your `switch` statement doesn't really make sense.

`switch (note)` says you want to compare the value of `note`, but then `case (note < 10)` says you want to compare it to the result of `(note < 10)`.

You're effectively asking whether `note` is equal to `(note < 10)`, i.e. `note == (note < 10)`.

What you can do is something like

```
switch (note) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 6:
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9:
        ...
        break;
    case 10:
    case 11:
    case 12:
        ...
        break;
```

But as you can see, this gets very tedious. `switch` is not designed for range-based comparisons. The best solution in your case is to just use an `if`/`else if` chain.

Comment: Thus, setting `switch(true)` allows the code to run as expected :)

Comment: @NickParsons Right, but I think that's an abuse of the `switch` statement. :-)

Comment: yes, I agree, if statment is much better for this kind of thing

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ***true*** instead of ***note***

`switch(note)` -> `switch(true)`

Because the condition you have for case will always result in true and false.and you're trying to compare it with a number which doesn't matches with any case so it will go to the default directly.

```js
let note = Number(prompt("Quel note as tu eu au baccalauréat?"));

switch (true) {
  case (note < 10):
   console.log("Tu es refusé, retente ta chance l'année prochaine");
    break;
  case ((note >= 10) && (note <= 12)):
   console.log("Tu as réussi l'éxamen, félicitations");
    break;
  case (note > 12):
   console.log("Félicitations, tu as réussi ton examen avec mention");
    break;
  default: console.log("Entre une note comprise entre 0 et 20")
  }
```

**P.S** - In such cases using `if else` is better option than `switch`.

Answer (score 0):

That was what i was looking for:

```
let note = parseInt(prompt("Quel note as tu eu au baccalauréat?"));

if ((note < 0) || (note > 20)) {console.log("Entre une note comprise entre 0 et 20")}
else if (note < 10) {console.log("Tu as raté ton examen")}
else if ((note => 10) && (note <= 12)) {console.log("Félicitations")}
else if ((note > 12) && (note <= 20)) {console.log("Tu as réussi ton examen avec   mention")}
```

Thanks for your help guys

Answer (score -4):

```
let note = Number(prompt("Quel note as tu eu au baccalauréat?"));
```

in place of Number try to use parseInt

`let note = parseInt(prompt("Quel note as tu eu au baccalauréat?"));`

It may Solve your problem

Comment: It's not the problem with `Number` read up the other answers what was actual problem.